# How to encode Django Exception Value like "\xce\xa5\xb7\xb4\xc1\xcb" to make it humreadable

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

My Django project Exception Value show in the browser is like this:

> Exception Value:
>
> ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]\xce\xa5\xb7\xb4\xc1\xcb PRIMARY KEY \xd4\xbc\xca\xf8 'PK_*Station*_30F848ED'\xa1\xa3\xb2\xbb\xc4\xdc\xd4\xda\xb6\xd4\xcf\xf3 'dbo.Station' \xd6\xd0\xb2\xe5\xc8\xeb\xd6\xd8\xb8\xb4\xbc\xfc\xa1\xa3 (2627) (SQLExecDirectW); [01000] [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]\xd3\xef\xbe\xe4\xd2\xd1\xd6\xd5\xd6\xb9\xa1\xa3 (3621)")

how to format the hex string like "\xce\xa5\xb7\xb4\xc1\xcb" to human readable string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
unicode(yourstring, "gb2312")
```

or

```
yourstring.decode("gb2312")
```

Comment: by the way, do you know how to make the Django exception error page show the right string "不能将值" instead of string like "\xce\xa5\xb7\xb4\xc1\xcb"?

Comment: Add  <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html;charset=utf-8">   to your Template page, and set the encoding of your html file to "utf-8"

Comment: Note: the encoding the error is in depends on the locale of the machine that generated it (here, Chinese, hence code page 936, the Windows superset of GB2312). Assuming you're on the same machine, you can use the encoding name `'mbcs'` to refer to whichever Windows code page is in use. However, this is only true for this kind of Windows-generated error; you can't necessarily assume it will be safe to decode any error string using `gb2312` or `mbcs`. Suggest using `.decode('mbcs', 'replace')` to at least avoid any errors from doing so.